# Using Primeng Datepicker how do I only enable the last day of months?

Tags: date, datepicker, primeng

So my question is pretty simple. I'd like to have specific dates that are enabled on a datepicker, like only the last day of any month, for example 30/06/2019, 31/07/2019

Primng Datepicker

```
<p-calendar formControlName="date"></p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple hack for your requirement.

In your component.html use min and max date and `(onMonthChange)` method to update `min` and `max` value of date when user changes the month. **Trick is just make min and max date equal to last day of the month.**

```html
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" tabindex="0" [maxDate]="maxDateValue" 
    [minDate]="minDateValue" readonlyInput="true" 
    (onMonthChange)="onMonthChange($event)">
</p-calendar>
```

And in component.ts file use below code:

```js
public maxDateValue: Date;
public minDateValue: Date;

ngOnInit() {
    this.setMinMaxDate();
}

setMinMaxDate() {
    var nowdate = new Date();
    this.maxDateValue = new Date(nowdate.getFullYear(), nowdate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
    this.minDateValue = new Date(nowdate.getFullYear(), nowdate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
}

// method to handle month change.
onMonthChange(e:any) {
    this.minDateValue = new Date(e.year, e.month, 0);
    this.maxDateValue = new Date(e.year, e.month, 0);
}
```

You must be thinking why at time of initialization I am using `nowdate.getMonth() + 1`, but inside `onMonthChange` only `e.month`, not adding + 1.

You need to go through this [find last and first date of month](https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/first-and-last-day-of-a-given-month-in-javascript.htm) article how to get the last and first date of a month and print the values of month in console and see the differences. Then you will understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need one day of each month you should use the month view

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateValue"
  view="month" dateFormat="mm/yy" 
  [yearNavigator]="true" 
  yearRange="2000:2030"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: Im using primeng 5 version. In which it doesnt support view month. any alternative solution?

Comment: @SVK i think it supports in version 5 as well you can find the same at this link https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5.2.7/#/calendar

Comment: If SVK's solution is not working due to version issue. Pls see another way to solve it.

Comment: No it doesnt support in 5.2.7